# How to combine 2 arrays to a new array

Tags: arrays, go

Imagine two functions `foo() [2]func()` and `bar() [3]func()`.

The goal is to enable the compiler to unroll these arrays later on.
Thus as much compile time information as possible should be maintained.
One idea is to construct a new array `[5]func()` out of the return of `foo` and `bar` calls.

Is there any way of combining these 2 returned arrays to a new array, that I do not know of?

Especially since I would like to have an operation which works even when the length of the returned arrays change.

Comment: "I would like to have an operation which works even when the length of the returned arrays change" you can't. Array's size is defined at compile time, which is why those compile-time optimizations are possible.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some options assuming the following:

```
f := foo()
b := bar()
```

There's a lot going in some of these options, but most of that happens at compile time. The constant expressions `len(f)`, `len(b)`, and `len(f) + len(b)` are evaluated at compile time.

Use a [composite literal](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Composite_literals):

```
c := [...]func(){f[0], f[1], b[0], b[1], b[2]}
```

Use [conversions](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions_to_and_from_a_string_type) to get pointers to the destination array and assign.

```
var c [len(f) + len(b)]func()
*((*[len(f)]func())(c[:len(f)])) = f
*((*[len(b)]func())(c[len(f):len(f) + len(b)])) = b
```

Use the [built-in copy](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#copy) function:

```
var c [len(f) + len(b)]func()
copy(c[0:], f[:])
copy(c[len(f):], b[:])
```

It is common to use slices in Go:

```
func foo() []func() { ... }
func bar() []func() { .... }

c := append(foo(), bar()...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one thing you could do that will work "even when the length of the returned arrays change":

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    sliceOfFuncs := []func(){}

    for _, f := range foo() {
        sliceOfFuncs = append(sliceOfFuncs, f)
    }
    fmt.Println(sliceOfFuncs)      // [0x480240 0x480260]
    fmt.Println(len(sliceOfFuncs)) // 2
    fmt.Println(cap(sliceOfFuncs)) // 2

    for _, f := range bar() {
        sliceOfFuncs = append(sliceOfFuncs, f)
    }
    fmt.Println(sliceOfFuncs)      // [0x4804a0 0x4804c0 0x4804e0 0x480500 0x480520]
    fmt.Println(len(sliceOfFuncs)) // 5
    fmt.Println(cap(sliceOfFuncs)) // 8 
    // Why 8? The capacity doubled once (2x2=4) when inserting the 3rd function
    // then doubled once again (4x2=8) when inserting the 5th function
    // that's how slices work.
}

func foo() [2]func() {
    return [2]func(){func() {}, func() {}}
}

func bar() [3]func() {
    return [3]func(){func() {}, func() {}, func() {}}
}
```

You could create a function for those for loops. [Here](https://go.dev/play/p/qAbLluO3kQI) an example.

Comment: Since your proposal uses slices, the compile time information about the length gets lost.

Comment: Yes but that's the price to pay in order to achieve that: "I would like to have an operation which works even when the length of the returned arrays change"

Comment: @IvanJijon [Use the builtin append function instead of a loop.](https://go.dev/play/p/ZSXh_ECcfUc).  Because `len(array)` is a constant expression, slices are not required to write code that's insensitive the length of the returned arrays.

Comment: @WandaMcintyre wonderful! I was trying `incomingFoo...` in stead of `incomingFoo[:]...`. Now I undersstand why it wasn't working.